# Customized chapter layout in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Any idea of how to make this layout in Microsoft Word (2016) for the chapter heading?

I want to have both lines as the same style so in generating the table of contents, it can be done automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Chapter heading]
Yes, it can be done. Here's how I did it. Because of the duplicated text, I don't consider this a very 'proper' solution, but it gives the desired result and doesn't require manual TC entries.

You can, of course, adjust font sizes, paragraph spacing, and positioning to fine-tune everything as you require. For this, I assume that you'll use the Heading 1 style for chapter headings.

1. Apply Heading 1 style (20-pt Times New Roman [TNR]), and type 'Chapter :'. Before the colon, insert a SEQ field code to autogenerate a chapter number: `{ SEQ chapter \* Arabic \n \* MERGEFORMAT }`. Insert 1 to 3 manual line breaks (Shift+Enter), depending on the line spacing for the style, and type the chapter title ('Performance Tests for the Algorithms'). Note that, in both the Navigation pane and the TOC, the number of spaces after the colon will match the number of line breaks that you insert; so ideally, you want to limit this number to 1 or 2. If all the chapter titles will fit on 1 line, you can probably get away with triple spacing for the Heading 1 style and a single line break, which is what I did.
2. You'll now mask the top line of the Heading 1 paragraph. Position the cursor at the beginning of the paragraph, and insert a rectangle shape with white fill and a 1-1/2 pt black border, set the height to **Absolute**, **36 pt** and the width to **Relative**, **100%** relative to **Margin**. Set the text wrapping to **In front of text** (if it isn't already), the horizontal position to **Alignment**, **Left** relative to **Margin**, and the vertical position to **Alignment**, **Top** relative to **Margin**. Select **Lock anchor**.
3. Position the cursor at the beginning of the Heading 1 paragraph, and insert a text box with no fill, no line (border), and no internal margins. Select **Resize shape to fit text**, and clear **Wrap text in shape**. Type 'Chapter' with 2 nonbreaking spaces after it. For the font, I used 30-pt bold TNR and set the line spacing to **Exactly** **27 pt**. Select the text inside (including the nonbreaking spaces), and toy with the font's **Position** setting to get all the text fully visible inside the text box (I used **Raised** by **1.5 pt**). Position the text box vertically so that the baseline of the text is aligned with the bottom of the border around the rectangle shape (I used **Absolute position**, **18 pt** below **Paragraph**), and horizontally so that the left edge is 1 point to left of left page margin (I had a 72-pt left margin, so I set to **Absolute position**, **71 pt** to right of **Page**). Select **Lock anchor**. Finally, select all the text again, and apply white paragraph shading.
4. Do basically the same thing again for the chapter number. I used 56-pt TNR with line spacing of **Exactly** **46 pt**, and set the font's **Position** to **Lowered** by **1.5 pt**. The vertical position for the text box is 1 pt above top page margin (I had a 72-pt top margin, so I set to **Absolute position**, **71 pt** below **Page**), and for the horizontal position, I just moved until it was a visually pleasing distance from the word 'Chapter' (the 2 nonbreaking spaces that you added after 'Chapter' give you some leeway here). For the number itself, you can manually type it, but I used a field code that picks up my autogenerated chapter number. If you want to do this, before you lock the anchor for the chapter number's text box, you need to insert a paragraph break after the chapter title and drag the anchor for the text box down to the new paragraph (if you don't do this, the number will appear as 0). Then insert this SEQ field code: `{ SEQ chapter \* Arabic \c \* MERGEFORMAT }` (note that it's identical to the first one, except that it has a `\c` switch instead of an `\n` switch, because you're referencing the last-generated chapter # instead of generating a new one).

And that's it.

Comment: Hi, yes please do give more details on it, and how to create the TOC out of it.

Comment: I've updated my original answer with detailed steps. I also found a way to have it all in one style, so that manual table of content entries aren't required.